# Usb Debugging not working after rebooting pc

Tags: android, usb-debugging

I am developing android apps in eclipse. everything is working fine two days ago. due to some reason i had to install a fresh copy of windows, in new window I installed `jdk-7u51-windows-i586` and start eclipse. now **USB debugging** with real device is not working. I am using Window 7 ultimate 32-bit. I tried Micromax A77 android 4.2.2, Samsung Galaxy S4 but none of the device able to install app directly from PC.
Also I install `Google USB Driver`. But not worked.

Comment: connect your device as media deviec not as usb mass storage . also ensure that your device have enabled usb debugging in developer options.

Comment: I am connecting device as media device and usb debugging is also enable in developer option

Comment: I restarted it more than 10 times but on debug time it launch virtual device instead of detecting real device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install "Moborobo" Software and try 
http://www.moborobo.com/products/moborobo.html

Comment: But two days ago it is working fine without moborobo

Comment: Hi Tinku, as you have installed new OS(Windows), previously installed drivers are not present. Just try to install multipurpose drivers(like Moborobo) or vendor specific drivers(like Samsung Kies).

Comment: I had the same issue, no way to debug with USB after rebooting. Moborobo solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Samsung Kies?

http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP

Comment: But two days ago it is working fine without these keys

Comment: @TinkuRana Yes, but you stated that you installed a new version of your OS, therefore it may not be updated with the latest drivers etc. I had this exact problem before and it worked after I installed Kies.

Comment: thanks tpbapp but abhishwke answer solved my problam, but +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

Update Android ADT to latest It may work